# Javascript code works in Chrome, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, express, firefox

I created simple web page using react and express. One module contains simple form with text input field, email input field and submit button and on submit it should send the mail to me, containing data from input fields. I used nodemail to create this sending mail thing! Luckily it works on chrome, unluckily it doesnt work on other browsers( firefox, IE, chrome on mobile ).

I found out that the problem is not in the backend side, but in the function connecting frontend with backend, but after that I got stuck and dont know what to do :(

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    var newMessage = {
        msg_sender: this.state.msg_sender,
        msg_content: this.state.msg_content
        }
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/message", newMessage)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log("Error! " + err)
            );
    };
```

That is the part connecting frontend with backend - as I said, it works fine in chrome, but doesnt in other browsers.

Comment: For ie it is probably due to it not having arrow function support. As for firefox make sure it is updated and look for errors in console

Comment: did you get any errors in console?

Comment: I did not, but I found out that the problem is in ```axios.post("http://localhost:4000/message", newMessage)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log("Error! " + err)
            );``` But I dont really know where :(

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Tagras! I hope you find this to be a great resource. i've written out an answer for your problem below. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrows functions are still a relatively new feature in JavaScript and unfortunately some browsers are still not up-to-date and likely never will be able to support them (Looking at you Internet Explorer).

There's a couple of ways to work around this.

1) You could rework all your arrow functions into standard functions:

```
onSubmit = function(e){
    var newMessage = {
        msg_sender: this.state.msg_sender,
        msg_content: this.state.msg_content
        }
    var axiosSetup = axios.create({
         baseURL: "http://localhost:4000"
    })

        axiosSetup.post("/message", newMessage)
            .then(function(res){ console.log(res.data) })
            .catch(function(err){ console.log("Error! " + err) })
            );
    };
```

2) You can integrate Babel in your application, which is a compiler that converts your javascript into compatible code for all browsers:

https://babeljs.io/

If you're building application for browser-compatibility it will also be in your best interest to check out mozilla's web developer guide which is a great reference to check if your code will work on other browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Alternatively, you can also use JavaScript's native fetch API. The benefit being that you do not have to install any libraries and its setup for use will be the same across all browsers

```
onSubmit = function(e){
    var newMessage = {
        msg_sender: this.state.msg_sender,
        msg_content: this.state.msg_content
   }
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/message', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: newMessage
    })
    .then(function(res){ console.log(res.json()) })
    .catch(function(err){ console.log("Error! " + err) })

};
```

See documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I think you missed removal of an arrow function on the first line.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing all the arrows function into standard ones did not help for firefox. What happens is after submitting the form, the variable newMessage is created in function, but the axios.post(...) does not pass the value to server side. That is so annoying! haha

Comment: @Tagras, darn I'm sorry to hear that. Have you already verified that this is an issue just in Firefox. Does this work fine in Chrome?

Comment: @Tagras ah okay I think I know what went wrong. Can you see my updated answer and see if that works for you?

Comment: Now it doesnt work in chrome and firefox neither. I realised that if function onSubmit is arrow function, everything works in chrome while doesnt work in other browsers, if onSubmit is not an arrow function, it doesnt work in any browser. How is that even possible, that it stopped working in chrome after just changing arrow function into standard one? :O //EDIT I added the line ```    onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
``` and now it works in chrome even with standard function. Firefox is still a problem

Comment: Hmm you might be on to something there :o. Do you mind sharing with me the error message you get when you try the code I provided with you above?

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Firstly, I didnt see that earlier, but in firefox's console i got message: 'The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.' and I am not sure what does it mean, maybe that is the issue! :P Secondly when I submit the form, I dont recieve any error message :( I am just at the beggining of the journey of web developer so the mistake I made can be pretty simple I guess :P

Comment: @Tagras. Yeah the server disconnecting sounds moreso like the real issue haha. There might be some underlying things beyond axios going on here that might be affecting your application. If axios is not working, you can also you the fetch API as well :). I can show you how to do that or direct you to some helpful docs.

Comment: I would be glad if you shared with me some docks about this API :) thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure! See the documentation above.